# Where is data stored in wordpress Media Upload?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

when we upload data in Upload Media Section where does it goes ?

- 1. DO it gets stored in Hosting provider server machine 2. Or do it gets stored in wordpress data base also how to increase the storage.
     I am using Google cloud platform as hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Media consists of the images, video, recordings, and files that you upload and use in your blog. Media is typically uploaded and inserted into the content when writing a Post or writing a Page.

They will store in the wp-content/uploads directory tree.

Please check link below to know more about wordpress media:

[https://wordpress.org/support/article/media-library-screen/]

To increase the Mysql storage, please note the effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits.[1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/table-size-limit.html)

If you are using the GCP StorageClass for your MySQL database, your database maximum size would be roughly the size of your storageclass.

Comment: Uploaded assets (media) such as images, videos, etc are not stored in MySQL. They are stored in the `wp-content/uploads` directory tree except when plugins have been installed that move these types of assets to Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thank you John, I have edited my answer accordingly.